# VBA giving method or data member not found for a method I have defined

Tags: class, vba

I have been trying to implement a very simple tree structure in VBA for some basic text parsing needs. The relevant code follows.

```
Private pLeaves() As CTree
Private numLeaves As Integer
Private leavesLen As Integer
Private iterate As Integer
Private pParent As CTree
Public pValue As Object

Public Sub class_initialize()
    ReDim pLeaves(10)
    leavesLen = 10
    numLeaves = 0
    Set pParent = Nothing
    iterate = 0
    Set pValue = Nothing

End Sub
Public Sub Class_terminate()
    'We'll leave it empty for now
    'if it looks like it's not working right we might change it
End Sub

Public Property Get Parent() As CTree
    Parent = pParent
End Property

Public Property Get Leaves() As CTree
    Leaves = pLeaves
End Property
Private Property Set Parent(ByRef p As CTree)
    Set pParent = p
End Property

Private Property Set value(ByRef value As Object)
    Set pValue = value
End Property


Public Sub Add_Leaf(ByRef value As Object)
    Dim n As Integer
    n = numLeaves
    If numLeaves >= leavesLen Then
       ReDim Preserve pLeaves(leavesLen + 10)
       leavesLen = leavesLen + 10
    End If
   Set pLeaves(n) = New CTree
   Set pLeaves(n).Parent = Me
   Set pLeaves(n).value = value
End Sub

Public Function DFFind_Leaf(value As Object) As CTree
    Dim i As Integer

    If pValue = value Then
        Set DFFind_Leaf = Me
        Return
    End If

    If numLeaves = 0 Then
        Set DFFind_Leaf = Nothing
        Return
    End If


    For i = 0 To numLeaves
        Set DFFind_Leaf = pLeaves(i).DFFind_Leaf(value)
        If DFFind_Leaf <> Nothing Then
            Return
        End If
    Next i

    Set DFFind_Leaf = Nothing
    Return
End Function
```

When I try to call the Add_Leaf function with an object though I end up getting a
*method or data member not found error* from VBA on the line where I'm trying to

```
set pLeaves(n).Parent= me
```

Any idea what the reason for that might be?

Edit: ok I figured out how to fix this. Changing the set property Parent(...) from private
to public fixed the problem. So apparently I don't quite understand what private exactly does in vba. If someone wants to explain how to do this without essentially exposing the variables for anyone to set as they want I would be grateful.

Comment: Parent property already exists in VBA, therefore I would consider it as a reserved word.

Comment: I confirmed your finding. It looks like VBA doesn't allow calls to private properties from the same module/class if they are on a different object than "me". You can only call private properties of the same object whose method is being invoked. I think that is silly of VBA. Also the error is misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Private` tells the VBA interpreter that the scope of the variable is restricted to the class/module only. You can therefore access it only inside of the original class, but not from the outside. `Public`on the other hand allows you to access the variable from the outside.

However, note that when working with classes, it is strongly discouraged to publicly expose any variables. Instead it is best practice to expose so called properties, using the `SET PROPERTY`and `GET PROPERTY` keywords.

I.e. instead of

```
Public Amount as Double
```

It is often better to use this approach:

```
Private mAmount as Double
Property Set Amount(amt as Double) 'Note that by default, properties are public
    If amt > 0 Then
        mAmount = amt
    Else
        mAmount = 0
    End If
End Property

Property Get Amount as Double
    Amount = mAmount
End Property
```

As you can see from this example, the advantage is that you can actually add additional verifications/modifications and therefore ensure the consistency.

In your example, you could consider to simply provide a *method*, i.e. a public sub, that adds a leave and takes care of all the settings, e.g.

```
Public Sub AddLeave(strName as String)
    Dim objLeave as New CTree
    objLeave.Init strName, Me
    mLeaves.Add objLeave, strName
End Sub

Public Sub Init(strName as String, objParent as CTree)
    Me.Name = strName
    Set Me.Parent = objParent
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahh you misunderstand my comment. I didn't make the pLeaves public. What I did do is make the `Property set value()` public and `property set parent()` public. And I really dislike having to do even that. I would much prefer keeping that private too. As the only way to change the parent should be through provided functions as I want to make sure the tree stays properly consistent.